# Why does C++ not support Variable-length arrays?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Variable length arrays in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/variable-length-arrays-in-c)

I am just curious, is there any particular reason why C++ does not allow variable length arrays?

Comment: Duplicate of [Variable length arrays in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/variable-length-arrays-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two reasons:

1. C++ is based on C89 (the C standard as published in 1989). VLAs were only introduced in C99.
2. C++ has `std::vector<>` and a whole bunch of other containers, which is why I believe that C++ will never bother with VLAs. It already had them when VLAs were invented for C.

Answer (score 2):

What about `std::vector`?

edit: sorry I missundertood your question.

Comment: I'm not complaining, I'm asking why.

Answer (score 0):

The STL includes a Vector class to use. Technically, you could use an array whose index variable is a pointer, leading to a "variable length" array.

Comment: I understand your second point to refer to dynamic arrays. But C has had these, too, from the very beginning.