# Array double datatype

Tags: c++, arrays, allocation

Can someone tell me why this code doesn't work? The user inputs a number, let's say 10, and it's saved into an int num. I want to make a double datatype array which can store 10 or num amount of doubles. Why do I keep getting an error when I write it this way?

```
int num;
cin >> num;
double list[num];
```

Why is it the above three lines don't work but if I change num in last like to 10 or any other integer it works fine?

```
int num;
cin >> num;
double list[10];
```

Comment: C++ does not allow declaring arrays with a runtime value as the number of entries.

Comment: [Why does C++ not support Variable-length arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782628/why-does-c-not-support-variable-length-arrays)

Comment: And if you want the number to vary: `#include <vector>` `int num; cin >> num; std::vector<int> list(num);`

Comment: thanks guys. Totally makes sence